Display Layered Navigation on CMS page
I am displaying the products on the CMS page using the pagebuilder with such conditions. Product are loads on the frontend and it works well. Now i want to add the layered navigation on the left side, So user can filter out the products on selection.
Do you guys have any idea? Please help me.

1. Create a Custom Module
Directory Structure
Create the following directory structure for your custom module:
app/code/Meetanshi/LayeredNavigation

module.xml
Create app/code/Meetanshi/LayeredNavigation/etc/module.xml with the following content:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Meetanshi_LayeredNavigation" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>

registration.php
Create app/code/Meetanshi/LayeredNavigation/registration.php with the following content:
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Meetanshi_LayeredNavigation',
    __DIR__
);

2. Create the Layout XML File
cms_page_view.xml
Create app/code/Meetanshi/LayeredNavigation/view/frontend/layout/cms_page_view.xml with the following content:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <container name="catalog.leftnav" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="catalog-leftnav">
                <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="Magento_LayeredNavigation::layer/view.phtml"/>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>

3. Assign the Layout Update to Your CMS Page
Edit the CMS Page:
Navigate to Content > Pages in the Magento admin panel.
Select the CMS page you created or want to edit.
Go to the Design tab.
Add Layout Update XML:
In the Layout Update XML field, add the following code:
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <container name="catalog.leftnav" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="catalog-leftnav">
        <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="Magento_LayeredNavigation::layer/view.phtml"/>
    </container>
</referenceContainer>

4. Ensure Layered Navigation Works Correctly
Sometimes, layered navigation might not work out of the box on CMS pages because it depends on product collections and filters, which are usually tied to category or search results pages. You might need to extend the block class to ensure it works correctly.
Create a Custom Block (if necessary):
If necessary, create a custom block to handle the product collection and filtering logic. This step may vary depending on your specific requirements.
Override the Template:
You might need to override the default view.phtml file to customize it for your CMS page.
5. Enable and Deploy
Enable your module:
php bin/magento module:enable Meetanshi_LayeredNavigation
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Deploy static content:
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush

Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface
Try these commands and check
rm -rf generated
rm -rf var/*
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento setup:di:compile


Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterableAttributeListInterface in /var/www/html/mag244/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:121
